# Error correction technique for 4 kB of data with 10-15% bit errors in an embedded microcontroller?

Tags: error-correction, bit-error

I'm working with an embedded project that uses a 4 kB buffer. Every once in a while something happens which introduces 10-15% bit errors, scattered throughout the buffer. Can someone please recommend some error correction techniques that could solve this? My microcontroller is clocked at 60 MHz and it's acceptable if the encoding/decoding takes hundreds of milliseconds, but not seconds. Ideally it should be a solution where there is free source code available.

Comment: You'd need to work on the non-corrupted data first. How do you know when it corrupts before applying error correction? Sounds like you are better off solving the problem than working around it.

Comment: Yes, the data will have to be encoded and I need a larger buffer than 4 kBytes for that. I may or may not be notified in the source code right before the corruption occurs, I'm still waiting for an answer from support. The highest level of support has confirmed that this problem is unsolvable.

Comment: I don't understand how this data corruption occurs, is it in RAM, in flash, during transmission? The simplest technique would be, if you receive a packet with lots of errors, ask the sender to retransmit it...

Comment: It's RAM and it temporarily loses power, but I've tried it hundreds of times and the bit error rate never exceeds 15%.

Comment: "_it temporarily loses power_" ... can you not do something to address the issue, rather than trying to place a bandage on a largely unqualified and uncontrolled process (i.e: RAM losing its contents). You may want to look into bulk capacitance, or battery-backed / non-volatile RAM.

Comment: The highest level of support has confirmed that this problem is unsolvable.

Comment: You mentioned that above, but I presume the "_problem_" that is unsolvable is "_my RAM becomes corrupt after power failure_", not "_the RAM in this part is unstable when operating within the recommended parameters_". Resolving the power loss seems like the only sensible solution here, otherwise you _**will**_ loose data at some point, even if it only appears to be presenting ~15% errors at present. For example - how long do you lose power for, to what voltage does the supply sink... how controlled are these effects, and does extending either of them affect that 15% figure?

Comment: If the problem is "unsolvable" (and you accept that as such), then I'm not sure what more you're looking for -- what hope do we we have to solve it?

Comment: Encoding/decoding the data is not solving the ROOT problem, it's a workaround.

Comment: The question doesn't mention the type of microcontroller nor the storage requirements, but would something like [Intelligent System State Restoration after Power Failure with Compute Through Power Loss Utility](https://www.ti.com/tool/TIDM-FRAM-CTPL) help? It isn't clear if _"it temporarily loses power"_ is the use of energy harvesting of some other intermittent power source.

Comment: Well you could always use Reed-Solomon coding but your 10-15% probably depends on temperature, process etc so there would be no guarantee... Why not use a nonvolatile FRAM chip or a backup capacitor?

Comment: ... not to mention that "_10-15%_" is a high figure, and in that situation your best approach may just be storing the data multiple times (3+) and using the duplicates to "vote" on the result. For example, many schemes are only capable of detecting 2x bit-errors, and correcting 1x bit-error. Processing effort will likely increase sharply with improved performance. See the excellent [3Blue1Brown videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8jsijhllIA)

Comment: If your system is getting RAM corrupted - especially at that high rate - then you need to fix that first, by stabilizing your power supply for instance. If the errors seem to have no known hardware root cause, don't overlook the possibility that it’s a software issue only rears its ugly head when the system is doing something specific.

Comment: BCH codes can deal with this sort of mess but I think they need a lot of ram to compute.

Answer (score 4):

> every once in a while something happens which introduces 10-15% bit errors, scattered throughout the buffer

> it temporarily loses power

Unfortunately, it's quite unlikely you'll be able to correct so much corruption without storing *multiple* whole copies and using these to "*vote*" on the correct value... and even then, due to the nature of how the errors are appaering (randomly in unpowered RAM), you will be incredibly lucky to get valid data out.

To give you some context, 10-15% is a very high error rate - schemes exist that are able to detect multiple bit-errors and correct only a few... often "*SECDED*" (single error correction, double error detection)... see the excellent [3Blue1Brown videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X8jsijhllIA) on this topic.

You're working with ~4KiB of data, which is 32,768 bits... which for a ~15% error rate, results in ~4,195 errors, ***way*** beyond what a simple scheme could achieve. The figure is still ~76.8 errors for a small 64-byte block.

Error detection and correction is a hot topic at the moment, with our storage technologies being pushed harder and harder - DDR5 has on-die ECC, and high capacity flash storage is no longer a reliable medium, but rather a game of statistics / probabilities. The algorithms that go into these devices are closely guarded secrets, and I can almost guarantee that they're nowhere near your 15% ask either.

I know it's not what you want to hear, but you should focus efforts on resolving the power issues you have, not searching for a magical (and free!) solution. It may also be sensible for you to investigate non-volatile storage like FRAM or battery-backed RAM (many parts have an amount of this built-in!)

It's also worth reviewing your software, to ensure these errors are indeed caused by power issues, and not one or more bugs.

---

> The highest level of support has confirmed that this problem is unsolvable.

I presume "*the problem*" that is unsolvable is "*my RAM becomes corrupt after power failure*", not "*the RAM in this part is unstable when operating within the recommended parameters*".

Comment: ChatGPT says that Turbocode with code rate 1/2 (so I'd need an 8 kB buffer) and constraint length 7 or 9 should be able to handle 15% bit error rate. I don't know if it's hallucinating or if there's any truth to it. Is it feasible to have a Turbocode encoder and decoder in a microcontroller or is it too computationally heavy? What about LDPC?

Comment: Well, you'd have to re-run the encoder each time you write to the RAM -- how often does that occur? And you'd still be vulnerable while the encoder is running -- what's the probability of the corruption occuring during that interval? It should be clear that even with a huge investment of resources, your overall reliability would still be abysmal.

Comment: "_ChatGPT says ..._" put it in the bin (I think I need a policy of entirely disengaging from anyone who responds "_ChatGPT says ..._"). Do you own research, understand the problem and options available. Then try again.